# Rel on REST API collection links

Tags: http, rest, collections, href, crud

I'm working on a REST API, and one of my resources is a collection of other resources, so I should return something like that:

```
{
    "Links":[
        {
            "Href":"http://my.rest.api/document/1",
            "Rel":"something"
        },
        {
            "Href":"http://my.rest.api/document/2",
            "Rel":"something"
        }
    ]
}
```

My question is about the "rel" property. I don't really understand its use. Is it something to specify which HTTP method to use? Can somebody explain me?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HTML 4 defines a set of [link types](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-links). Key for their understanding is this sentence:

> User agents, search engines, etc. may interpret these link types in a variety of ways. For example, user agents may provide access to linked documents through a navigation bar.

The same is true for REST. Server and client must agree about the meaning for the possible values of  `rel`.  These come to mind:

- `parent`: the parent collection a Resource is a child of
- `next`: the next Resource in a collection (if the collection is ordered)
- `prev`: the previous Resource in a collection (if the collection is ordered)
- `children`: a collection of child resources

There can be many more. The concrete `rel` values heavily depend on your Resources.

**Edit:** The `rel` attributes say nothing about HTTP verbs. They only give a hint about the nature of the relation of the current Resource to a different Resource.

Answer (score 0):

They're a descriptor for how the target resource relates to the current resource. You can make your own up, or use established ones.

http://www.iana.org/assignments/link-relations/link-relations.xhtml

If they're stable in your API, then you can build client apps that look for the rel they're interested in from your links, then deference the `href` to advance to it.

For example, you may return:

```
"links":
[
    {
        "href": "/items",
        "rel": "collection"
    },
    {
        "href": "/items/123",
        "rel": "delete"
    }
]
```